# how to listen to AutocompleteSupportFragment no result found response

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to learn how to use the `AutocompleteSupportFragment` but I noticed the `PlaceSelectionListener` only has the `onPlaceSelected` and `onError` methods, it does not offer a method that is invoked when it does not find a place. 
How can I listen to `no result found` ?

Below is my code

```
if ( !Places.isInitialized() ) {
    Places.initialize( getApplicationContext(), getString( R.string.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY ) );
    autoCompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById( R.id.autoCompleteFragment );
    autoCompleteFragment.setHint( getString( R.string.search_address_hint ) );
    autoCompleteFragment.setPlaceFields( Arrays.asList( Place.Field.ID,
            Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.ADDRESS, Place.Field.LAT_LNG ) );
    autoCompleteFragment.setCountry( "ZM" );


    btnConfirm.setOnClickListener( v -> confirmAddress() );

    autoCompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener( new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            edtBuilding.setText( place.getName() );
            startIntentService( place.getLatLng() );
            adjustCamera( place.getLatLng() );
            mPresenter.addMarker( place.getLatLng(), place.getName(), place.getAddress(), ConfirmPickUpActivity.MARKER_NORMAL );
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            Log.i( TAG, "An error occurred: " + status );
        }
    } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably missed this page.
https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/api/net/PlacesStatusCodes

It is there, status code `NOT_FOUND`. In your code you have to write.

```
@Override
    public void onError(Status status) {
        Log.i( TAG, "An error occurred: " + status.getStatusCode () );
    }
```

Comment: `onError(Status)` is never called when an place is not found. I have tried it.

Comment: @AubryLungu , is onPlaceSelected working (when you found places)?

Comment: Yes it is but `onError` is not called when a place is not found.

Comment: It is strange. Well the method exists, but why it is not working needs more checking.

Comment: @amitava did u find any solution if there's no result found?

Comment: @SolaimanHossain , Extremely sorry, I am not practising coding actively for almost an year. I can not remember anything about this particular topic right now.